# jQuery. Check each item by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, there are some tags

```
<input value="1000" class="chrome-input" />
<input value="2000" class="chrome-input" />
```

How can I make manipulation with each value?
Here I can set value to each input. `$(".chrome-input").val("10");`
But what if I want multiply each value by `10`.

Something like that  `$(".chrome-input").val($(".chrome-input").val()*10);`

And I want to get that

```
<input value="10000" class="chrome-input" />
<input value="20000" class="chrome-input" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clean way of doing this is with the callback signature of [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val):

```
$('.chrome-input').val(function(i, oldVal) {
    return parseInt(oldVal, 10) * 10;
});
```

If you pass a function as the first argument of `val`, that function will be called on each element.  The second argument passed will be the current value of the element.  The return value of the function will be set as the new value.

Comment: Probably best to use `parseInt`, to defend against weird inputs like "0x100" and (on some implementations) "010".

Comment: Oh, this is cool. TIL .val() accepts a callback. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Amadan For what it's worth, most jQuery functions that set a value/property do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".chrome-input").each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  el.val(el.val() * 10);
});
```

Comment: ...and if the user types "0x100"? (Or, on some implementations, more plausibly "01000")

Comment: Depends who you write for. I'm perfectly fine with 01000 * 10 being 5120. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()` like so:

```
$('.chrome-input').each(function(i,ele){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.val( parseInt($this.val(),10) * 10 );
});
```

Comment: That's why I cached it to a variable, but good point nonetheless.

Comment: You didn't originally, when I made that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/vdTT4/

```
$(".chrome-input").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val() * 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".chrome-input").each(function(){var value = $(this).val(); $(this).val(value*10); });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use function `each()`

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
  alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

[link to jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)